# Gmail has stopped grouping messages with the same subject

Tags: gmail

Gmail is no longer grouping emails with the same subject (conversation view), just like it was in the "old days".

How can I group my mails in Gmail again?

Comment: Would you care to elaborate? How where they grouped? You tagged filters, do you mean that they should automatically get tagged when they match a certain criteria?

Answer (score 2):

Gmail - Settings (in dropdown menu in the upper right corner) - Conversation view on

I temporarily changed my locale to English an taken few printscreens:

[image: settings]

[image: conversation view]

Comment: @Jana: you are welcome! If you are satisfied, you can accept this answer. Visit this site's introductory [tour], please - it's a good way to learn basics on using this site, like what questions are good to ask here, how to accept answers and how to edit posts. Then you can practice editing and improve your question (like dropping the filter tag and adding general [tag:gmail] tag). It may be solved for you, but perhaps someone like you will have the same problem in the future and will find this question, so help them to find it helpful. And what's more: don't be afraid to ask other questions!